# google analitics GTM cuasing memory leaks, with angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks

I have GTM script, with my name and GTM code.

```
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','myNewName','GTM-XXXX');
```

Scenario without memory leak:

- Im entering into route A, getting memory snapshot and app uses 15MB memory.
- Im entering into route B, getting memory snapshot and app uses 7MB memory (everything is ok, angular/garbage collector deleted old route view DOM objects.

Memory leak scenario:

- image memory snapshot 1: Im entering into route A, getting memory snapshot and app uses 15MB memory.
- image memory snapshot 2: Im clicking somwhere in empty space, GTM doing something.
- image memory snapshot 3: Im entering into route B, getting memory snapshot and app uses 16MB memory (I don't know why, but DOM elements wans't removed from app memory)

[image: leak image]

I don't know why GTM after click, making memory leaks when changing routes. Does it attach object to window or do other weird staff, and angular/garbage collector doesn't remove them from memory?